# Investigating the differentiability of $f(x) = |\sin x |$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I'm given the function

$$f(x) = |\sin x |$$ and I'm asked to investigate its differentiability.

Well, from the graphic of $\sin x$ is clear that the function is differentiable at every point, except at $x = \pi k$ , where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, since at that point the limit with $h \to 0^-$ and $h \to 0^+$ are not equal.

I got this conclusion just by analyzing the graph of the function, but I'd appreciate is some of you can point out a way to reach this conclusion by applying the definition either of derivative or that of differential or by a more ''formal'' approach.

This is my attempt:

Since $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ then the function becomes

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin x &\mbox{if, }0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\\
-\sin x &\mbox{if, }-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x<0
\end{cases}$$

Consider the left-hand limit and right-hand limit at $x_0 = 0$. we have

$$\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} -\frac{\sin(0+h)-\sin(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(0+h)-\sin(0)}{h}$$

$$-\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}$$

Here I don't know how to consider the sign the left-hand limit (I'm somewhat rusty honestly). I'm not sure but if $$\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$$ We're done since the LH limit would not be equal to the RH limit (we'd have $-1=1$)

Comment: Your thoughts on the LHS are correct. Perhaps it would be useful to you if you would tell why you're not sure about it.

Comment: @GitGud I thought that for some reason $\lim_{h\to 0^{-}} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}=-1$ which whould give me  $1=1  $ above. I think some of my neurons are beginning to work just now: If  $h \to 0^- $ then  $h<0 $ and since  $\sin $ is an odd function  $\sin(h)<0 $ which gives  $\frac{\sin(h)}{h} >0 $ and by taking the limit we have  $1 $ as required.

Comment: That is correct. Personally I would avoid using the fact that $\sin$ is odd. "Near" $0$, $\sin$ is non-positive, period.

Comment: @GitGud I didn't get why (in this case) is better to avoid the fact that $\sin$ is odd.

Comment: It's (at best) taking a detour, plus it doesn't suffice that $\sin$ is odd, you also need to use the fact that $\sin$ is positive "near" $0^+$. In principle there's no reason why an odd function can't be positive on the negative numbers. It's also important to point out that you're working near $0$, because, as you know, $\sin$ is both positive and negative on the left of $0$. Still on why I think it's better to avoid the oddness thing, is this the problem suggested by this question: can you prove that $\sin$ is odd without first knowing that it's negative near $0^-$?

Comment: It is clear that at the point $x=0$ there are infinitely many tangent lines to the curve graph of the function (like what happen whith $f(x)=|x|$) so the derivative is not defined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way:

Since $f$ is even (similar reasoning applies to the other zero), if it was differentiable at zero, we would have $f'(0) = 0$. However,
$\lim_{h \to 0, h > 0} {f(x) - f(0) \over x} = 1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: This is a pretty neat way. Thanks!!